# Idle constraint ignored with Firebase's JobDispatcher

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I have set a Job using Firebase JobDispatcher like that :

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        .setService(EclipseLauncher.class)
        .setTag(JOB_TAG)
        .addConstraint(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
        .addConstraint(Constraint.DEVICE_IDLE)
        .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
        .setReplaceCurrent(true)
        .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(5,9999999))
        .build();
```

What I want is for this job to be executed ONLY if the device is connected to a network (WIFI or 3-4G) and the device's screen is turned off.
But here the Idle constraint seems to be completly ignored. Sometimes the job will be started when the app is running, and always start when the app goes to the background.
Worse, if I set the Trigger to `Trigger.NOW` or if I do not set any, the job is immediatly started.

Do I misunderstand whant Idle means ?